# latest downloaded ISO file cant install bootloader on to flashdrive

Tags: system-installation

Please help me!!!
Installation commenced fine at the beginning but stuck at during installing grub or bootloader? How to fix this prob to install Elementary OS on to a flash drive?

Comment: How have you install your system? Are you currently using Windows, Mac OS X, Linux? I have tried UNetbootin on Linux to install eOS 0.3.1 and works fine. If you can't solve your problem try this one you can also get it on Windows and Mac OS X. If it still can't work try to check errors on your usb pen or try an other one.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by trying to force UEFI during install. Use the appropriate install method for your system, you should really never have to force UEFI. Try installing Elementary OS with your computers Legacy Boot option instead and see if you get better results.